# Send a big form without reloading the page using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony

I am using symfony2, I generate a big form (around 200 fields)

I'd like to add a function to save end continue editing the form.

I know that I can send a form using JQuery:

```
$('#myFormId').submit();
```

But this reload the page

I can also send my form using ajax, I think this is the solution but how to easily put all my fields in a data variable ? This is the problem

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to prevent the default action of submitting the form, which also redirects the page.
Then you send the ajax call, and you can serialize the form with jQuery's `serialize()` to get all the data from the form, like so :

```
$('#myFormId').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url : $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks It works :) I didn't know serialize for a form, il can be very usefull